# gedit 3.8.3 several plugins do not work

Tags: 13.10, gedit

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10 (and thus Gedit 3.8.3), and several plugins I was using in Gedit (like "session save" and Strl-Tab navigation throught tabs) are now unavailable.
Can you help get them back ?

Thanks
gedit-plugins is installed already

Answer (score 1):

- [Gedit 3.8.3 only supports python3 plugins](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/issues/121)
- [gedit 3.8 plugins: Python loader broken](https://bugs.archlinux.org/index.php?do=details&task_id=34976)
- [Old plugins are incompatible with Ubuntu 13.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gdp/+bug/1241849)

These three links indicate that old (Python 2) plugins will not work with the new Gedit.

Comment: Thanks, I had this figured out, now the question is how to save sessins, how to boorkmark with no bug, how to CTRL-TAB through tabs please ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what to say about that.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer for the "session saver" plugin : https://github.com/sphax3d/gedit-sessionsaver

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work for me. I'm using gedit 3.14.3 on Xubuntu 14.10.